# How to check if password has at least one of the allowed special characters?

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have function that checks password. This function should check if password values contains at least one of the special charters that I listed in the description. Here is example:

```js
$('input[type=password]').keyup(function() {
  var pswd = $(this).val();

  //validate the length
  if (pswd.length < 8) {
    $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
  } else {
    $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
  }

  //validate letter
  if (pswd.match(/[a-z]/)) {
    $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
  } else {
    $('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
  }

  //validate capital letter
  if (pswd.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
    $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
  } else {
    $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
  }

  //validate special character
  if (pswd.match(/[!"#$%&'()*+,-.:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]/)) {
    $('#character').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
  } else {
    $('#character').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
  }

  //validate number
  if (pswd.match(/\d/)) {
    $('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
  } else {
    $('#number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
  }
}).focus(function() {
  $('#pswd_info').show();
}).blur(function() {
  $('#pswd_info').hide();
});
```

```css
.form-group.required .control-label:after {
   content: "*";
   color: red;
}
.password-container {
 position: relative;
}
#pswd_info {
    position:absolute;
    width:250px;
    font-size:.875em;
}
#pswd_info::before {
    content: "\25B2";
    position:absolute;
    top:-12px;
    left:45%;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:14px;
    color:#ddd;
    text-shadow:none;
    display:block;
}
#pswd_info ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
#pswd_info li {
 list-style: none;
}
.invalid {
    padding-left: 22px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #ec3f41;
}
.valid {
    padding-left: 22px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #3a7d34;
}
#pswd_info {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group required password-container">
  <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="temp_password" id="temp_password" placeholder="Enter Password" maxlength="64" required>
  <small id="passwordHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Special characters allowed:  <span class="text-danger">!"#$%&'()*+,-.:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~</span></small>
  <div id="pswd_info" class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h5>Password requirements:</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul>
        <li id="letter" class="invalid">At least <strong>one letter</strong></li>
        <li id="capital" class="invalid">At least <strong>one capital letter</strong></li>
        <li id="number" class="invalid">At least <strong>one number</strong></li>
        <li id="character" class="invalid">At least <strong>one special character</strong></li>
        <li id="length" class="invalid">Be at least <strong>8 characters</strong></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the code above there is if statement that looking for the match for one of the special characters. i found the problem. My regular expression works until I enter `\` , regex doesn't recognize backslash. Also If I enter any of the characters after backslash I see that `li` with id `letter` turns green. That is a bug and I'm not sure why that would be set to valid. I guess that my regex is breaking because of the `\` and I'm not sure what is the correct way to check for back and forward slash in JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation)

Comment: Your regex `[A-z]` should be `[a-z]`. I'd also suggest you at least use `[^a-zA-Z\d]` instead of a list of symbols.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew creates a range of what? All allowed special characters?

Comment: Ok, `[,-.]` matches `,`, `-` or `.`, they are just consecutive in the ASCII table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165991/discussion-between-ctwheels-and-espresso-coffee).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is there a way to check for backslash in regex javascript ?

Comment: To match a backslash, it must be doubled: `/\\/`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have tied this but still doesn't match the backslash  pswd.match(/[!"#$%&'()*+,-.:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~]/) as you can see I have double backslash inside square brackets but still does not work.

Comment: Come on, I bet your string does not contain a backslash. You must be using  something like `var s = "\s"`, right? You must use `var s = "\\s"`. `"\s"` = `s`, and `"\\s"` = `\s`.

Comment: I'm just letting user an option to enter backslash if they want. That should be allowed in my regexp...

Answer (score 2):

You can vastly simplify your expression with lookaheads:

```
^
(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])
(?=[^!"#$%&'()*+,-.:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]*[!"#$%&'()*+,-.:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~])
(?=\D*\d).{8,}
$
```

Without `verbose` mode:

```
^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^!"#$%&'()*+,-.:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]*[!"#$%&'()*+,-.:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~])(?=\D*\d).{8,}$
```

This makes use of the principle of contrasts.
Please also note that `[A-z]` matches [**more characters than you think**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926).

---

This is what I mean:

```
$('input[type=password]').keyup(function() {
  var pswd = $(this).val();
  if (pwsd.match(/^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^!"#$%&'()*+,-.:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]*[!"#$%&'()*+,-.:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~])(?=\D*\d).{8,}$/)) {
     // now, it is valid
  } else {
     // invalid
  }
}).focus(function() {
  $('#pswd_info').show();
}).blur(function() {
  $('#pswd_info').hide();
});
```

Comment: So what I should replace in my line where I'm looking for special characters? I did make a mistake and should be [a-z] not [A-z]. Thanks.

Comment: @espresso_coffee: Everything from `//validate the length` up to `//validate number` (inclusive) can be deleted.

Comment: I still can't see how your code will replace mine and still work the same. Can you please show an example?

Comment: Can't open the link.

Comment: @espresso_coffee: See the updated answer then, have posted the code there.